# "For the time being" vs. "in the meantime"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I am confused when to use "For the time being" and when to use "In the meantime". Are they interchangeable? Can you please explain with some examples?

Comment: Related :http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73849/for-the-time-being-vs-for-now

Answer (score 12):

In the meantime means until something expected happens, or while something else is happening:

> Your computer won't arrive till Thursday. In the meantime, you can use
>   Jude's.

for the time being means for a limited period:

> Leave the ironing for the time being - I'll do it later.

From the http://dictionary.cambridge.org website.

Answer (score 0):

> in the meantime
> the period of time between two things; the period of time between now and when something is supposed to happen.
> -- [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+meantime)
>
> for the time being
> if you describe how a situation will be for the time being, you mean it will be like that for a period of time, but may change in the future
> -- [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+the+time+being)

I believe that they are essentially interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No. Ok it may seem to very much unclear to understand in the starting but let me explain it to you.

**In the mean time** means while something is happening. and **Time being** means while you are free, so that you can utilise your time...So yes you can use it interchangeable but only when you are `free`. Similarly No when you are not `free`.

Comment: First of all meantime is one word, *mean time* is ambiguous. Second, after a period/full stop (.) the word that follows always starts with a capital letter. Third, after an ellipses (...) leave a space... like that. Fourth, I have difficulty understanding your penultimate sentence. Could you explain yourself better? Lastly, you did not provide any examples as requested by the OP. Damn! I've just seen the time date, Aug 30. I've been preaching to a ghost.